# Is it mandatory to put files in /srv/salt folder to transfer from master to minion

Tags: salt-stack

Is it mandatory to put files in /srv/salt folder of master to transfer file/directory from master to connected minions.

Can we transfer files without using salt file server

1) Can we transfer files without using salt file server? 
2) Also the document says "You can't run interactive scripts" . 
Does it mean there are some limitations to execute arbitrary linux commands with cmd.run eg. we can run salt "*" cmd.run ['ls -l /home'] . 
Similarly can we run commands like scp,ssh with cmd.run.

Comment: `ls -l /home` is not an interactive script

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the salt file server. You can also set the source to for example a http location. In that case though, you must also declare the hash of the file, for example:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite:
    file.managed:
        - source: http://example.com/mysite
        - source_hash: abc123....
```

Answer (score 0):

The document suggests the default location as /srv/salt as mentioned [here](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/master.html#roots-master-s-local-file-server)

Comment: Can we transfer files without using salt file server?

Comment: Yes, you can transfer files without using the salt file server